# How to build lpeg on windows?

Tags: lua, mingw32, gcc4.8, lpeg

I've downloaded lpeg source code from http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/lpeg-0.12.tar.gz
How to get the dll? I can't do it with the makefile included. I'm using mingw32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this simple batch file running from lpeg folder:

```
set LUA_DIR=D:\lua-5.2
gcc -O2 -shared -s -I %LUA_DIR%\src -L %LUA_DIR%\src -o lpeg.dll lptree.c lpvm.c lpcap.c lpcode.c lpprint.c -llua52
```

Just set LUA_DIR folder to the folder with your Lua installation; it works with both Lua 5.1 and Lua 5.2.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I never knew it was so easy to build a lua library.

Answer (score 0):

First change the `LUADIR` variable to the correct location of your Lua include files. Then add the following make target (using the correct path to your Lua DLL):

```
mingw: $(FILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared $(FILES) -o lpeg.dll C:\path\to\lua52.dll
```

I also had to change `CC` from `gcc` to `mingw32-gcc`, but that might just be my broken MinGW installation.

```
make mingw
```

should work now.